# Page title is showing category name as well in the google search results

Tags: title

I am using WordPress 5.4.1 with yoast seo plugin on my blog (buybestproducts.in). In the meta box, title is separated by a hypen followed by site title. Everything looks fine. However, when google search is performed then the title is followed by site title and then category name is also displayed. I do not know why this is happening. Can anyone help me on this issue?
[image]